# Consumindo Json[Array & Object] no Android

Tags: android, json

De acordo com o **comentário de alguns usuários daqui do fórum**, **eu li alguns artigos falando sobre mais ou menos o que eu queria fazer**.

- **Artigo lido:**

> [consumindo JSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44161/consumindo-json)

**A partir** disto eu **tentei criar o meu próprio código**, **porém** estou com **sérios problemas**, **os quais são**:

> **1)** Não sei como "juntar" a classe do JsonRestFull com a Classe Shopping, para que eu possa reutilizar o código do Json para outras
>   classes.
>
> **2)** Utilizando a pergunta **(1)**, não sei como pegar os dados que se encontram no JSON e fazer uma comparação.
>   **3)** Não sei se o código está correto.

**JSONRestFull.java**

```
package com.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Neoris;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;


import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by th on 30/06/17.
 */

public class JSONRestFull {

    // Define o URL do Servidor para obter os dados do Book
    private static final String LOGTAG = "Json";
    private String mServerJsonURL = "http://www.teste.com/shopping.json";
    private String mBookDataJSONFullUrl;

    // Indica se o aplicativo está atualmente carregando os dados do Book
    private boolean mIsLoadingBookData = false;

    // Dados do Shopping ativo
    private Shopping mShoppingData;


    /**
     * Obtém os dados do Book de um objeto JSON
     */

    private class GetBookDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mIsLoadingBookData = true;

            // Inicialize o url completo do BOOK atual para pesquisar
            // para os dados do JSON
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sBuilder.append(mServerJsonURL);

            mBookDataJSONFullUrl = sBuilder.toString();
        }


        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;

            try {
                // Conecta ao Servidor para obter os dados do Book no JSON
                URL url = new URL(mBookDataJSONFullUrl);
                conectarServidorJson(url);

                int status = connection.getResponseCode();

                // Verifica se o URL do JSON existe e a conexão
                // foi bem sucedida
                if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    // Limpa as variáveis ​​de dados da Classe
                    mShoppingData = null;
                }

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }

                // Limpa qualquer referência antiga dos mData
                limpaReferenciaAntiga(mShoppingData);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());

                // Gera um novo objeto do JSON Shopping
                mShoppingData = new Shopping();
                geraNovoObjetoJson(jsonObject, mShoppingData);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(LOGTAG, "Couldn't get Json's. e: " + e);
            } finally {
                connection.disconnect();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setmServerJsonURL(String mServerJsonURL) {
        this.mServerJsonURL = mServerJsonURL;
    }

    private void conectarServidorJson(URL url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        connection.connect();
    }

    private void limpaReferenciaAntiga (Shopping mShoppingData){
        if(mShoppingData != null){
            mShoppingData = null;
        }
    }

    private void geraNovoObjetoJson (JSONObject jsonObject, Shopping mShoppingData) throws JSONException {

        // Gera os Objetos Json do Shopping
        mShoppingData.setNome(jsonObject.getString("nome"));
        mShoppingData.setLicenseKey(jsonObject.getString("licenseKey"));
        mShoppingData.setAccessKey(jsonObject.getString("acessKey"));
        mShoppingData.setSecretKey(jsonObject.getString("secretKey"));
        mShoppingData.setLAT_1(jsonObject.getDouble("LAT_1"));
        mShoppingData.setLAT_2(jsonObject.getDouble("LAT_2"));
        mShoppingData.setLONG_1(jsonObject.getDouble("LONGI_1"));
        mShoppingData.setLONG_2(jsonObject.getDouble("LONGI_2"));
    }



}
```

**Shopping.json**

```
{
    "shoppingsObj": {
        "shoppings": [{
                "nome": "Bangu Shopping",
                "licenseKey": "Ad84Z0z/////AAAAGSgcOhPVvkoniWypHW2Dfsw+iX69si/",
                "acessKey": "f854427",
                "secretKey": "16208b",
                "LAT_1": ["-22.879832"],
                "LAT_2": ["-22.877738"],
                "LONGI_1:": ["-43.468601"],
                "LONGI_2:": ["-43.465978"]
            },
            {
                "nome": "Boulevard Shopping Campos",
                "licenseKey": "AULCxLD/////AAAAGa6JoRhAAk70lshljOUpGeN7XUgbJ/",
                "acessKey": "6ad29c",
                "secretKey": "370db",
                "LAT_1": ["-21.755484"],
                "LAT_2": ["-21.753139"],
                "LONGI_1:": ["-41.350870"],
                "LONGI_2:": ["-41.346417"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Você quer ler o arquivo Shopping.json certo?! Qual o problema desse JSONRestFull.java? Você quer então usar esses dados buscado do json em outra classe?!

Comment: Você está usando parcelable ou serializable?

Comment: @acklay , 1) Eu quero ler o shopping.json e utilizar o shoppingObj.lat e shopping.Long comparando e percorrendo todos os seus vetores, para verificar se o usuário está dentro do perímetro. Caso ele esteja dentro, ele percorrera o shopping.nome e shopping.keys deste shopping e fará o "set". 2) Eu não sei se este código do JsonRestFull está correto. 3) Eu não sei te dizer, só li o tópico que deixei na pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu considerei a resposta do @Leonardo Lima
Porém alterei o código e utilizei o **Volley**

Para quem quer aprender a fazer o mesmo que eu, utilizei o seguinte:

```
package com.vuforia.samples.Books.ui.ActivityList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.vuforia.samples.Books.R;
import com.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Neoris.GPSTracker;
import com.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Neoris.Shopping;
import com.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Neoris.VolleyAppController;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by th on 05/07/17.
 */

public class ShoppingsJsonScreen extends Activity {

    // json array response url
    private String urlJsonArry = "http://jsonvu.esy.es/shoppings.json";

    private static String TAG = ShoppingsJsonScreen.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnMakeObjectRequest, btnMakeArrayRequest;

    // Progress dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private TextView txtResponse;

    // temporary string to show the parsed response
    private String jsonResponse;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.shoppings_json_screen);

        btnMakeArrayRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnArrayRequest);
        txtResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Carregando Json...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        btnMakeArrayRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // making json array request
                makeJsonArrayRequest();
            }
        });

    }

    private void showpDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hidepDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    /**
     * Method to make json array request where response starts with [
     * */
    private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {

        showpDialog();

        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        try {
                            // Parsing json array response
                            // loop through each json object
                            jsonResponse = "";
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject shoppingObj = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                                JSONObject shoppingInfoObj = shoppingObj.getJSONObject("informacoes");

                                Double shoppingLAT_1 = shoppingObj.getDouble("LAT_1");
                                Double shoppingLAT_2 = shoppingObj.getDouble("LAT_2");
                                Double shoppingLONG_1 = shoppingObj.getDouble("LONG_1");
                                Double shoppingLONG_2 = shoppingObj.getDouble("LONG_2");

                                String shoppingNome = shoppingInfoObj.getString("nome");
                                String shoppingLicenseKey = shoppingInfoObj.getString("licenseKey");
                                String shoppingAccessKey = shoppingInfoObj.getString("accessKey");
                                String shoppingSecretKey = shoppingInfoObj.getString("secretKey");


                                // Cria o Class Object
                                GPSTracker gps;
                                Shopping shop;
                                gps = new GPSTracker(ShoppingsJsonScreen.this);
                                shop = new Shopping(ShoppingsJsonScreen.this);

                                if((gps.getLatitude() >= shoppingLAT_1 && gps.getLatitude() <= shoppingLAT_2)
                                        && (gps.getLongitude() >= shoppingLONG_1 && gps.getLongitude() <= shoppingLONG_2)){
                                    jsonResponse += "LAT_1: " + shoppingLAT_1 + "\n\n";
                                    jsonResponse += "LAT_2: " + shoppingLAT_2 + "\n\n";
                                    jsonResponse += "LONG_1: " + shoppingLONG_1 + "\n\n";
                                    jsonResponse += "LONG_2: " + shoppingLONG_2 + "\n\n";

                                    jsonResponse += "Nome: " + shoppingNome + "\n\n";
                                    jsonResponse += "LicenseKey: " + shoppingLicenseKey + "\n\n";
                                    jsonResponse += "AccessKey: " + shoppingAccessKey + "\n\n";
                                    jsonResponse += "SecretKey: " + shoppingSecretKey + "\n\n";

                                    // Adiciona as Informações Obtidas do determinado Shopping
                                    shop.setShoppingNome(shoppingNome);
                                    shop.setShoppingLicenseKey(shoppingLicenseKey);
                                    shop.setShoppingAccessKey(shoppingAccessKey);
                                    shop.setShoppingSecretKey(shoppingSecretKey);


                                }
                            }

                            txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Erro: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Erro: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        VolleyAppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ao interpretar o JSON, um pedaço de sua estrutura foi desconsiderada: o objeto **shoppingsObj** e a array **shoppings** contida dentro dele. As latitudes e longitudes também estão dentro de um array.

Vale notar também que seu método `geraNovoObjetoJson` parte do princípio de que o JSON conterá somente um shopping, quando na verdade ele pode conter vários. Inclusive, no JSON do seu exemplo há dois shoppings.

Uma outra versão do seu método `geraNovoObjetoJson` seria:

```
private void geraNovoObjetoJson (JSONObject jsonObject, List<Shopping> mShoppingData) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject shoppingsObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("shoppingsObj");
    JSONArray shoppingsJson = shoppingsObj.getJSONArray("shoppings");
    for (int i = 0; i < shoppingsJson.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject shoppingJson = shoppingsJson.getJSONObject(i);
      // Gera os Objetos Json do Shopping
      Shopping shopping = new Shopping();
      shopping.setNome(shoppingJson.getString("nome"));
      shopping.setLicenseKey(shoppingJson.getString("licenseKey"));
      shopping.setAccessKey(shoppingJson.getString("acessKey"));
      shopping.setLat1(shoppingJson.getJSONArray("LAT_1").getDouble(0));
      shopping.setLat2(shoppingJson.getJSONArray("LAT_2").getDouble(0));
      shopping.setLon1(shoppingJson.getJSONArray("LONGI_1").getDouble(0));
      shopping.setLon1(shoppingJson.getJSONArray("LONGI_2").getDouble(0));
      mShoppingData.add(shopping);
    }
  }
```

Repare que eu alterei o tipo da variável `mShoppingData` de `Shopping` para `List<Shopping>`. Esta versão do método também considera que que sempre existirá pelo menos 1 objeto dentro dos arrays `LAT_1`, `LAT_2`, `LONGI_1` e `LONGI_2`.

---

Interpretar JSON manualmente da forma que você está fazendo pode se tornar custoso a longo prazo.

Durante estudos ou em projetos pequenos não há grandes problemas. Para projetos maiores recomendo utilizar bibliotecas como [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) ou [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) ou , que convertem POJOs para JSON e vice-versa.