# Como ler Json com Android

Tags: android, json, array

Gostaria de saber como que eu leio json de dois jeitos diferentes.

1 - Tenho um Json

```
{"nome": "JOA", "cpf": 7.4417, "idade": "15"},{"nome": "PAT", "cpf": 8.5528, "idade": "20"}"};
```

Este mesmo consigo ler e jogar em variaveis, mas apenas a primeira parte, gostaria de saber como obter o valor da segunda parte do json.

Segue o código em java:

```
JSONObject obj;
String nome = "", cpf = "", idade = "";
String teste = "{\"nome\": \"JOA\", \"cpf\": 7.4417, \"idade\": \"15\"},{\"nome\": \"PAT\", \"cpf\": 8.5528, \"idade\": \"20\"}";
try {
    obj = new JSONObject(teste);
    nome = obj.getString("nome");
    cpf = obj.getString("cpf");
    idade = obj.getString("idade");

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), nome, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch (JSONException ex)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse JSON esta errado:

```
{\"nome\": \"JOA\", \"cpf\": 7.4417, \"idade\": \"15\"},{\"nome\": \"PAT\", \"cpf\": 8.5528, \"idade\": \"20\"};
```

Este formato está quebrado e não vai ser lido, você provavelmente quer é algo como:

```
[{\"nome\": \"JOA\", \"cpf\": 7.4417, \"idade\": \"15\"},{\"nome\": \"PAT\", \"cpf\": 8.5528, \"idade\": \"20\"}]
```

Com `[item1, item2]`, então como eu já respondi em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44168/3635

Use `JSONArray` para pegar arrays `[]` e `JSONObject` para pegar "objetos" `{...}`, basta iterar assim:

```
JSONObject obj;

String teste = "[{\"nome\": \"JOA\", \"cpf\": 7.4417, \"idade\": \"15\"},{\"nome\": \"PAT\", \"cpf\": 8.5528, \"idade\": \"20\"}]";

//Faz o parse
JSONArray minhaArray = new JSONArray(teste);

//Itera
for (int i = 0; i < trendsArray.length(); i++) {

    //Pega o item atual
    obj = new JSONObject(minhaArray.getString(i));

    obj.getString("nome");
    obj.getString("cpf");
    obj.getString("idade");
}
```

Se quiser pegar da parte "2", como o array começa a iterar do zero então use o `1`, assim: `.getString(1)`:

```
String teste = "[{\"nome\": \"JOA\", \"cpf\": 7.4417, \"idade\": \"15\"},{\"nome\": \"PAT\", \"cpf\": 8.5528, \"idade\": \"20\"}]";

//Faz o parse
JSONArray minhaArray = new JSONArray(teste);

//Pega o item atual
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(minhaArray.getString(1)); // Pega o item 2

nome = obj.getString("nome");
cpf = obj.getString("cpf");
idade = obj.getString("idade");
```

Comment: Toma aqui meu +1; =D

Comment: Perfeito, entendi agora o conceito de Arrey e Objetos dentro do Json.

Comment: @PatrickCamargo isso resolveu seu problema? Se sim marque a resposta como correta por favor, se não souber como fazer leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635

Answer (score 0):

Também pode ler um JSON usando GSON (uma biblioteca que converte objetos Java em JSON e vice-versa)

Exemplo de uso:

```
public class ApiCliente {

    private Cliente cliente;

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    class Cliente {

        private int id;
        private String nome;
        private String RG;
        private String email;

        public Cliente() {
        }

        public Cliente(int id, String nome, String RG, String email) {
            this.id = id;
            this.nome = nome;
            this.RG = RG;
            this.email = email;
        }

        public int getId() { return id; }
        public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

        public String getNome() { return nome; }
        public void setNome(String nome) { this.nome = nome; }

        public String getRG() { return RG; }
        public void setRG(String RG) { this.RG = RG; }

        public String getEmail() { return email; }
        public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Cliente{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", nome='" + nome + '\'' +
                    ", RG='" + RG + '\'' +
                    ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }//fecha classe
}//fecha classe

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //JSON ESTÁTICO - JAVA
        String jsonCliente = "{cliente:{\"id\":\"1\",\"nome\":\"maria\",\"RG\":\"132456\",\"email\":\"maria@gmail.com\"}}";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ApiCliente cli = gson.fromJson(jsonCliente,ApiCliente.class);

        Toast.makeText(
                getBaseContext(),
                "OBJETO EM JAVA: "+cli.getCliente().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }//fecha oncreate
}//fecha classe
```

GSON precisa importar o compile:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
```